# My boss wants to get rid of me - what should I do?

Tags: human-resources, termination, legal, performance, singapore

Brief story: I work as IT support in a bank. I am an analyst who just graduated from university and my boss is a VP

- 10-May-2019: My boss told me they will put me on an informal "performance improvement plan"(i.e. PIP) due to my recent poor performance (I did make a few small mistakes in previous months).
- 13-17 May 2019: I was sick for the whole week and clarified with my boss on PIP's expectations and measurements.
- 20-24 May 2019: I followed the plan and reported progress to my boss. She asked me some really strange questions which I couldn't answer (e.g. to recite all column names in a feed text file with nearly 50 columns)
- 27-May-2019: my boss declared improvement plan failed since I didn't make enough progress (i.e. I couldn't answer her above query)
- 27 May: I understood from HR that the next step is my boss would put me into a formal PIP with HR and this will be recorded into my P-file.
- 28-May-2019: I told my boss not to put me into formal PIP as I don't want to be recorded (PIP record may affect me during reference check). My boss agreed and asked me to tell her when I would resign.
- 29-May-2019 to 5-June-2019: I took a long leave and went for multiple interviews (I started to apply for jobs since 10 May 2019)
- 6 June 2019: my boss chased me on resignation-date. I told her I need to discuss with my family and she agreed.

I know I can't drag much longer. I either have to resign or my boss will submit me to HR for PIP. I can't sue my boss or my company since they are not doing anything illegal.

I have 2 verbal offers since the start of this week but no written offer yet. Besides, I am also interviewing with other companies. All these take time.

Can anyone advise me on what I should do now? As you can see, my boss really wants to get rid of me and this 1 week PIP is just an excuse to fire me legally.

Comment: Is (not) there any notice period?

Comment: Hi Sourav, notice period is one month

Comment: but am afraid that being put on PIP Or terminated may affect future employer references check

Comment: @Sourav, formal PIP, per HR, usually last from 6-8 weeks before declare failure or success. That gives me enough time for job hunting. But am just afraid PIP will affect future employer reference check.

Comment: tchen003 - I'm taking your words for it, but I can't think of a scenario where being in PIP in one company will be known / disclosed for reference / backgrounds checks. Does it really matter, you know for sure? Otherwise, what @Abigail said make more sense - _let them fire you_.

Comment: @Sourav, I am not sure as well. I read from other websites : there is no law prohbit future company ask about PIP history and no law prohibit current company provide such references. However this happen less frequently due to companies afraid of getting into lawsuits. In other words, it’s like ‘black swan’

Comment: @SouravGhosh If you let them fire you, you have to tell that you got fired in any upcoming interview, which isn't a killer, but typically seen as a negative aspect whereas you switching on your own isn't. So I'd only go the "let them fire you" route in countries where this gives you a benefit, e.g. *significantly* more time or additional money or the chance that they find out they cannot fire you (and this only if you really need the job, as working there will not be fun if they want to get rid of you but legally cannot).

Comment: @FrankHopkins As I said, if there are consequences of getting fired, then that's not the wisest of choices, but in case a letting go is equivalent to end of contract / termination due to resignation - obviously to allow them to fire you will buy you some more time, in this case, at least.

Comment: @SouravGhosh well my point is that there are always some negative consequences of getting fired versus going on your own wrt to future job interviews. So in my perspective to go the let-them-fire you route needs to have benefits that outweigh the negatives.  And here a little probability estimation comes in - normally you don't want to quit without the next job lined up, so letting them fire you might give you the time to find another job. But if it's pretty certain the firing will take place quite soon anyway, that benefit might not outweigh the negative cost.

Comment: This: `recite all column names in a feed text file with nearly 50 columns` could be seen as bullying. If this was done in writing, and a third party confirms that it is bullying, then the boss could have great difficulty firing you. Not with a counter allegation of management bulling on the table.

Comment: @Frank, I called up my country labor authority and they told me that getting fired (instead of lay off) will not entice me for unemployment benefits or N+1 salary etc. In Singapore, we are employed-at-will so company may give you 1 month notice and pay you salary when you are serving notice.

Comment: @Underverse, I do have voice recording and also written email from my boss. I think it may be a good idea to find out whether it's bullying or not by asking some lawyer or authority.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere,  you are absolutely right. I buy myself some time from 27 May until now. But I guess I cant buy more.

Comment: @tchen003 Look up the HR policy on bullying and see if the definition fits. Requiring an employee to do something which is either not impossible or not required or obviously too difficult and then judging them on their failure to achieve is normally counted as bullying. If it meets the definition then how you use this or approach the manage is important - legal advice may be needed.

Comment: Can you join a union at work and get them to advise you for this or act in your interest?

Comment: With all due kindness I think trying to spin this into a claim of being bullied is just clutching at straws - and not particularly substantial ones at that. I mean by all means you can contact the [MOM](https://services.mom.gov.sg/efeedback/Forms/eFeedback.aspx) and ask but on the face of it I have to say the notion is verging on the absurd IMO.

Comment: @tchen003 I'd be careful with mentioning the voice recording if you did not tell your boss you'd make it. In many jurisdictions making a voice recording of someone without notifying them in advance is against the law, inadmissible evidence and your boss could easily use it as evidence that there is a total lack of trust and a broken employer-employee relationship on your part. (I don't know the laws in Singapore though!)

Comment: Have you discussed your boss's management style with her? Seems like what you're saying is her questions were unfair because they were irrelevant to your job, so her push to get you to quit is bullying. If this does go to HR, make sure you bring this up.

Comment: If being put on a PIP for a "few small mistakes over the course of a couple of months" is how they treat a new college grad, you're probably better off not working there anyway. Of course, what you see as "a few small mistakes" may be glaring errors in their eyes.

Comment: I have to agree with @FreeMan.  I work in IT and knowing column names was expected of me in 20 years, if they existed I would have just looked them up and no one would have cared.    If you were'nt leaving I would go and ask point blank, why know this information is expected and were this expectation was previously mentioned.  Further, I would ask would you rather have someone who's made a few mistake and learned from them, or start over and have someone else make those mistakes and possibly more.

Comment: @user70848, well my boss can easily defend herself that this is not bullying since she has been in this job for years and knows better than whoever I try to escalate. But what I can say is: I got no raise nor bonus for my past 2 performance reviews. You might argue that probably in US ( or whatever countries) no pay increment or bonus is normal. But during my verbal offer, even the new company HR was so surprised that they asked me why. I believe this is bullying but in a legal way.

Comment: @cybernard, show you my converation with boss: “do you know what is the file name for xxx” “yes, the file name is yyy”, “so do u know the directory where yyy is?”, “yes, is under zzz”, “do you know how many columns in yyy and what are they?”, “sorry I dont know but estimate 30-40 columns? I only remember a few column names such as blah blah blah”, “ok, you failed”.      In summary, there is always something you can’t remember and you must fail.

Comment: @Freeman, again she has her own justification. Show you an example: we were responsible for act on night alert on rotation basis. There was one night that my teammate forgot to respond when she was on duty. After remind her via whatsapp for multiple times, I have to volunteer to help out since no one is responding. The next day, my boss told me my response to this system alert is slow. But my volunteer to help was never spoken out and that lady who missed out the alert was never mentioned as well. This was actually one of her evidences to put me on PIP. Funny right?

Comment: @JamesJJ, I spoke to head of HR advisor in my region. She briefied me about the process: boss put employee on informal PIP for whatever how long boss would determine, then employee is put on formal PIP with HR for 6-8 weeks, then PIP success, nothing happens, PIP fail, clean your table and go home. Being put on formal PIP and job termination by company will be recorded in P file. I have to make decisions by myself as they cant advise me anything

Comment: It sounds like you are caught in a quasi-socialist country (Germany, France, Canada maybe?) which provides high employment protection laws. This would explain why they can't just straight fire you - which would be easier for everybody - and instead have to resort to a costly, torturous process of legally justifying to get rid of you, preferably by you resigning. But the events you described which lead to that seem quite dubious... just leave. Consider not talking excessively about that in applications - they can't know the truth, so keep it short and neutral to show that you weren't the issue.

Comment: @Battle, Singapore. You are right they don’t want to go to lengthy firing process and ask me to resign voluntarily. After all, there is no compensation package in Singapore if you are fored due to performance issue.

Answer (score 52):

I'm going to try to be gentle here but I think you've taken this as far as you can - you talk about your boss "wanting to get rid of" you and the PIP being an "excuse to fire" but let's be realistic here your boss has so far gone to some pretty substantial lengths to help you.

The first "PIP" wasn't formal - presumably to avoid the negative associations of having it on your record (that you acknowledge are a possiblity), you didn't improve on that so they gave you the option to resign and avoid having a firing on your employment history, they gave you the onus of when to resign and over a week later are *still* giving you more time to discuss it with your family! And all you can do is act as if they are persecuting you!

Unless you need to avoid resigning (say to qualify for unemployment benefits or similar) then I think you just need to resign now. You mention some verbal offers already - you only need one of those to pan out during your notice period and you're fine. It's either that or you are going to get that PIP, and a firing, and probably an ex-boss whose good will with you has run out - and you might need a bit more of that good will when it comes time to be getting references.

It's really not worth riding that horse into the ground and exhausting their good will completely for the sake of what at most is going to be another week's worth of being employed there.

Comment: Hi Motosubatsu, thanks for the advice. Very good point.

Comment: Not sure being asked to correctly recite 50 column headings is "being helpful" or even a valid assessment of abilities and progress

Comment: @SolarMike difficult to say whether reciting 50 column headings is a valid assessment without knowing the context of them and how they relate to the particular duties of the role. But does it really matter? The OP's boss clearly had options to take a tougher stance then they have shown but chose not to, I'm not suggesting the boss should be nominated for sainthood or anything but they are clearly trying to help the OP soften their exit a bit.

Comment: @motosubatsu, from context of my job scope, I don't see reciting these info as necessary. I can't comment on what's her intention of 1 week PIP with weird questions. I do appreciate her on-boarded me to this company and exposed me the working field.

Comment: @tchen003 we don't know all the details, without further context it could be a valid way to gauge how familiar you are with a certain topic (typically the real requirement would not be to know all of them by heart but some of them at least by semantic content) or totally nonsensical.

Comment: @motosubatsu you are unreasonably dismissing the posibillity of OP's boss having other reasons than performance to try to fire him. We don't have any facts to judge, but it's at least as likely she just needs to shorten the staff or has some personal reason, especially given the strange performance measurement, which can be achieved by an incompetent IT imposer just as well as by any senior dev (if not better)

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevesky they are in an at-will jurisdiction if she wanted the OP gone ASAP for some nefarious reason they would have been given their notice on May 10th and be three days from being unemployed rather than still having not given in their notice. If bound by internal policy to do a PIP first there wouldn't have been the informal PIP. Ultimately though unless the reasons are something that the OP can prove to be discrimination as defined by local legislation then the exact reason is irrelevant, the job is done, all the OP can do is mitigate any damage and move on. I'm advising how.

Comment: If the OP's boss were the owner of the company, then

Comment: @velimir, I think the true reason is my personal conflict with one of my boss’s favourite teammate. But again, I cant prove it.

Comment: @motosubatsu, from your id, I assume you are asian as well. Then you may know in ancient times, when a large army is fightig a small army, large army will usually surround its enemies but leave a space open for enemies to run away. This is not good will, it’s to encourage small army to run away. If large army leave no space for small army, small army have no choice but to fight with their lives which will cost more to large army. I hope that explains “good will”

Comment: @motosabatsu I do agree with the course of action you suggest 100%. But I do think that misinterpreting the situation can have a negative impact on OPs career, because a developer needs to be confident in his knowledge and being convinced that he was fired for not performing, if the case is different might greatly mislead him. My 2 cents for OP are to follow your advice and closely inspect the  mistakes he made, making sure he will not repeat them.

Comment: Hard to deduce, whether OP's boss really tried to help them or not. My initial impression is that this is a classic case of, "if theywant to get rid of you, there will always be a way". Either way, this is a harsh situation and we all can probably agree on the OP not being in a position to salvage this job. Now all steps towards a new employment must be the primary focus.

Comment: @tchen003 I don't think comparing this situation to a military strategy to limit the number of death is relevant. In your situation there is nothing you can do to damage the company. And anything you could do to damage the boss or the company would be coming back to bite you. Obviously we can't say why your boss wants you to leave. But from what you've told us, it seems like they've given you every chance to find a new job, or get better at this one. And apart from the "recite 50 columns" part, I can't see anything that show malice in what you've described.

Answer (score 19):

**The optimal path for your CV / future interviews is typically you leaving for another job, rather than you being fired or you leaving without any job lined up.**

So, since you already have verbal offers, next time you meet your boss you should let them know that you are in negotiations with another company for a follow-up contract. You can ask her how flexible you can be, e.g. whether it would be okay to mutually agree on leaving faster than the notice period once you have lined up the next contract.

That way your boss knows you are actually working on leaving. For your boss it's way less hassle if you leave on your own than if she has to go through company processes to have you fired, so she might not be thaaat concerned whether it's a month earlier or later if she at least knows it's gonna happen.

This would also allow you to sweeten the deal for a future employer - in case they need you fast, you can switch quickly after signing the contract. As soon as you have a written offer and signed it, you can quit your job.

Comment: hi Frank, this is the best answer I got. You are right since she want me out of the team for whatever reason. So I could tell her that I have a few offers line up and buy more time. However, I disagree with you on "leaving faster than the notice period " because if I left the company during notice period, per company policy, I need to make payment-in-lieu to make up for the remaining days. Thank you once again

Comment: @tchen003 that's why I wrote "mutually agree on leaving faster". That agreement obviously needs to address any concerns both parties might have. A contract can always (legal obstacles aside) be amended if both parties agree on the amendment. So it would be possible to agree that the company lets you stop working within the notice period and waves its rights to these payments if you quit within the next [agreed time-period] or so. If no such agreement can be found, sure, then take the full notice period.

Comment: @tchen003 The reasoning behind the suggestion is that to your boss, the main factor of how fast she wants you to leave is how long she has you in her budget as a cost factor. Thus, agreeing on cutting the notice period short gives her incentive to allow for a later quit date as it at least indicates a good chance it won't cost her (much) additional money while saving her paperwork and potential legal trouble etc. Obviously it shouldn't be agreed to in a form that hurts you, but as you want to leave, it can be an advantage for you as well, if you can leave faster once an offer is made.

Comment: Great advice! will talk to my boss in this case. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 13):

As I see, you have two choices:

- Keep stalling and end up being put into PIP (and most likely the outcome will be negative anyways, based on the previous experiences), and finally end up being terminated.
- Resign, leave gracefully and search for other opportunities.

Point to note, in current scenario, in either of the cases, you might run into the situation of staying unemployed after quitting / being let go, but in second case, you won't have  PIP in your record.

You also mention that there is a notice period of one month, so at least you have got that much time to find you a new job, considering you submit your resignation letter immediately.

I'd say, your boss is actually handling the situation very gracefully and with sort of a preferential treatment towards you - you were given a chance of informal PIP, they respected your request to avoid formal PIP, they even allowed you to decide on the resignation date with two times extension period to allow you to think (and to probably find another job in the meantime) - I'd not discount that. They could have been more formal and process-oriented, if they wished. So, leave in good terms, announce the day of your resignation on the next meeting.

You need to take the final call, anyways.

Comment: It is much easier to get a new job while you currently have a job.

Comment: I agree with @Underverse : the proper order to do things is "find a new opportunity and only then gracefully resign".

Comment: Isn't there a third choice? Or, maybe, a 1a: Keep stalling and stay employed *while you look for a new job?* The way your first bullet is worded it makes it sound like you're talking about just passively waiting until you get fired. But maybe you meant what I'm suggesting?

Comment: Yes, but that option has run out. OP is not in the position to hold on to their job anylonger, so they cannot decide to get a job before resigning. Besides, it seems this has already happened, as OP already has verbal offers.

Answer (score 8):

I am the original poster. 10 month has pased and I have been working in a great company learning new things.

I spoke to my ex-colleague and got confirmed I got fired not due to performance but rather my ex-boss at that time was tasked to force away one team member from upper management. If I didnt quit, my ex-boss would be in trouble.

I heard from other departments that the manager just frankly told employees that they were fired due to company organization change, some managers even helped employee to find a even better job by leveraging on his/her contacts. I was not that lucky to have a manager like that.

I see my current company has laid off as well. I guess even if we are in Financial IT industry, the job security is always not that high unless you are real high flyer. So I shouldn't be afraid too much of being fired again.

I will just do my job well, learn new things, be more approachable. But if I am still fired, just move on for a new job.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the world of IT you often have influences, including supervisors, who have a very limited scope of rationale when it comes to their demands - such as demanding you memorize all of the columns in  a query.

Most IT Managers/Leaders understand that it is our job to break things every single day then take the figurative "hammer" and "fix it".

Getting released from a job almost insures that you cannot use them as a reference for future applications.

My advice is to hit the applications as hard as possible, do not use this position as a reference (you can always say unless I am a final candidate) - and FYI - at least in the U.S. - it is illegal for your current employer to say anything that is opinionated outside of the specific scope of your job duties.